# Apps Script Template HTML Breaks on Success Handler

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Searched, but wasn't able to find any similar problems or solutions.

I have some templated HTML which builds a form based on data from a spreadsheet, as I have a variable number of dropdowns and options in those dropdowns.

On click of submit I want to display a spinning gif to the user, so they know it is processing.

If the backend code in code.gs passes the input through all the tests I want to update a div with a success message, if any of the checks fail with an error message.

I've got this to work, before with the create .createHtmlOutputFromFile method, but now with .createTemplateFromFile it just wipes the whole page.

HTML template

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300);
#container{
    padding-left:10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
#header{
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
form{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:10px;
}
#nameField{
   width:400px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
}
#reqIndic{
   color:#FF0000;
}
select{
    margin-top: 5px;
    width:150px;
}
#submit{
  margin-top:20px;
  width:125px;
  height:40px;
}
#confirmation{
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height:60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#padding{
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height:60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h2>Cheltenham Classic</h2>
    </div>
    <br>
    <form name="projectsForm">
        <span id="reqIndic">&#42;</span>
        <span> Name</span>
        <input id="nameField" type="text" name="name" required>
        <br>
        <? for (var race in races) { ?>
            <span><?= race ?></span>
            <select>
                <? for (var i = 0; i < races[race].length; i++) { ?>
                    <option value="<?= races[race][i] ?>"><?= races[race][i] ?></option>
                <? } ?>
            </select>
            <br>
        <? } ?>

        <br>

        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Form" onclick="google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler(updateDiv)
              .onEvent(this.parentNode);spinner()">
    </form>

</div>
<div id="confirmation" style ="text-align:center"></div>
<div id="padding" style ="text-align:center"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateDiv(returnValue){
        alert('debug');
        var div = document.getElementById('confirmation');
        if(returnValue == false){
            var errStr = '<p>ERROR: Please check your rankings for blank fields or multiple entries of the same project and re-submit your rankings</p>';

            div.innerHTML = errStr;
        }
        else{
            div.innerHTML = '<p>Success! Your results were submitted successfully</p>';
        }

    }


    function spinner(){
      var div = document.getElementById('confirmation');

      div.innerHTML = '<img src="http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/32.gif">'
    }
</script>
```

Back end code

I've cut the onEvent function right down to just returning an object with a key value pair without making any checks.

The updateDiv function runs and the alert shows then the entire page is wiped.

```
function doGet(){
  var raceForm = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('RaceForm');
  raceForm.races = getRaces();
  return raceForm.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function onEvent(e){
  return {'valid': true};
}

function getRaces(){
  var url = //spreadsheet url
  var wb = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = wb.getSheetByName('Races Log');

  var racesObj = {};

  var wsValues = ws.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i <wsValues.length;i++){
    var race = wsValues[i][0];
    racesObj[race] = [];
    racesObj[race].push('0');
    for(var j = 1; j<wsValues[i].length;j++){
      racesObj[race].push(wsValues[i][j]);
    }
  }

  return racesObj;
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This line: `/* @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300); */` is causing an error in the browser.

Comment: Can you provide a hard coded `racesObj` so we have something to work with, and know what you expect the object to look like?

Answer (score 0):

If I hard code the `racesObj` object:

```
var racesObj = {one:["one","two"], two:["one", "two"], "races":["belmont", "kentucky"]};
```

The page looks like this:  (Using the template)

[image: Chatham Classic]

If I click the submit button, I get this:

[image: Success]